# How to get scope of an IPv6 host?

Tags: linux, bash, ip-address, ipv6

I don't have much knowledge about the IPv6 protocol, so sorry if the question sounds stupid.
When I retrieve the list of all IPv6 addresses in my network, I get a field named scope, as shown below :

```
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::11/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::10/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::13/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::21d:9ff:fe69:2c50/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::12/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::15/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::14/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::5/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::17/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::6/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::16/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::7/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::19/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::8/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::18/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::9/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::1b/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::a/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::1a/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::b/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::1d/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::c/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::1c/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::d/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::1f/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::e/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::1e/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2001:470:1:82::f/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
```

In my application, I need to get those addresses for which the scope is 'Link'. I could have used a system call to ifconfig and then parsed the output to extract corresponding addresses. But the problem is, I'm using the call to getifaddrs(), which returns a linked list of structure ifaddr, given as :

```
       struct ifaddrs {
           struct ifaddrs  *ifa_next;    /* Next item in list */
           char            *ifa_name;    /* Name of interface */
           unsigned int     ifa_flags;   /* Flags from SIOCGIFFLAGS */
           struct sockaddr *ifa_addr;    /* Address of interface */
           struct sockaddr *ifa_netmask; /* Netmask of interface */
           union {
               struct sockaddr *ifu_broadaddr;
                                /* Broadcast address of interface */
               struct sockaddr *ifu_dstaddr;
                                /* Point-to-point destination address */
           } ifa_ifu;
       #define              ifa_broadaddr ifa_ifu.ifu_broadaddr
       #define              ifa_dstaddr   ifa_ifu.ifu_dstaddr
           void            *ifa_data;    /* Address-specific data */
       };
```

The question is : how to get the addresses with 'Link' scope from this list ?

Comment: Why the close votes? Explanations would be nice.

Comment: @EBGreen because the question is asking about how to go about coding a routine to extract interface details.  This is best on stackoverflow, so the close votes are to migrate the question to the site that can better answer it.

Comment: @Manish, you don't need to do anything about this, if it is a good fit the migration will happen automatically and you can continue activity on your question there.

Comment: Works for me. I just think it helps users especially new ones if they get some commentary along with the close votes.

Comment: @Manish, it is polite to either accept an answer as correct (click the tick), or leave a comment as to why it didn't help. If you do not do this, you may find nobody will answer your questions in future!

Comment: @JeremyVisser : Sorry for that, I should have replied to the comments first. I am going to do so now. Thanks a lot, my bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this would simply be to check whether the address falls within `fe80::/10`. The [IPv6 address space](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-address-space/ipv6-address-space.xml) is available from IANA, which details the possible scopes available.

I downloaded the source code to [net-tools](http://net-tools.berlios.de/) (the source package for ifconfig), and it looks like they parse `/proc/net/if_inet6`. (Comments are my own additions in the following code — also the below is extremely abridged and will most certainly not compile.)

```
/* some defines collected around the place: */

#define _PATH_PROCNET_IFINET6   "/proc/net/if_inet6"
#define IPV6_ADDR_LOOPBACK      0x0010U
#define IPV6_ADDR_LINKLOCAL     0x0020U
#define IPV6_ADDR_SITELOCAL     0x0040U
#define IPV6_ADDR_COMPATv4      0x0080U

int scope; /* among other stuff */

/* looks like here we parse the contents of /proc/net/if_inet6: */

if ((f = fopen(_PATH_PROCNET_IFINET6, "r")) != NULL) {
while (fscanf(f, "%4s%4s%4s%4s%4s%4s%4s%4s %02x %02x %02x %02x %20s\n",
          addr6p[0], addr6p[1], addr6p[2], addr6p[3],
          addr6p[4], addr6p[5], addr6p[6], addr6p[7],
      &if_idx, &plen, &scope, &dad_status, devname) != EOF) {

/* slightly later: */

printf(_(" Scope:"));
switch (scope) {
case 0:
    printf(_("Global"));
    break;
case IPV6_ADDR_LINKLOCAL:
    printf(_("Link"));
    break;
case IPV6_ADDR_SITELOCAL:
    printf(_("Site"));
    break;
case IPV6_ADDR_COMPATv4:
    printf(_("Compat"));
    break;
case IPV6_ADDR_LOOPBACK:
    printf(_("Host"));
    break;
default:
    printf(_("Unknown"));
}
```

So let's have a look at what the above is parsing:

```
$ cat /proc/net/if_inet6
20010db8000008000000000000000001 03 40 00 00     eth0
fe800000000000000000000000004321 03 40 20 80     eth0
00000000000000000000000000000001 01 80 10 80       lo
```

So you can see the third column from the left (`0x00` Global, `0x20` Link-Local, and `0x10` Loopback) is the scope. Using the above constants from the net-tools code you can work out what they mean. Further investigation would be required to determine a more authoritative source for such constants, and also whether parsing `/proc/net/if_inet6` is your best option.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeremy, this really helped me a lot to understand. As you said, I simply checked whether the address falls within the range specified, ie `fe80::/10` and this works for me.

Comment: No worries. Sometimes the most simple solution is the best!

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please explain. I am willing to edit my answer to improve it (or edit it yourself accordingly).

Answer (score 8):

There are helper macros to assist:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 s6;
if (IN6_IS_ADDR_LINKLOCAL(&s6.sin6_addr)) {
  puts ("link-local");
} else if (IN6_IS_ADDR_SITELOCAL(&s6.sin6_addr)) {
  puts ("site-local");
} else if (IN6_IS_ADDR_V4MAPPED(&s6.sin6_addr)) {
  puts ("v4mapped");
} else if (IN6_IS_ADDR_V4COMPAT(&s6.sin6_addr)) {
  puts ("v4compat");
} else if (IN6_IS_ADDR_LOOPBACK(&s6.sin6_addr)) {
  puts ("host");
} else if (IN6_IS_ADDR_UNSPECIFIED(&s6.sin6_addr)) {
  puts ("unspecified");
} else {
  puts ("global");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the scope is stored explicitly in that data structure. However, you can infer the scope from the IP address itself. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Address_scopes