# how to find ipv4 address scope name (link, host and global) as compared with ipv6 scope in C linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ipv6, ipv4

Here i am not talking about the scope id its about the scope name (host, link, site or global).
How to compare/get scopes of ipv4 address as well as for ipv6.

Comment: IPv4 does not _have_ a fully developed set of scopes like IPv6. You should define more clearly what information you want to determine about the IPv4 addresses you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

A straight-forward solution would be to compare the address with the prefixes from [this list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses#Reserved_IPv4_addresses).

Comment: Phillip: Its only for reserved IP addresses. But I need to find the IP addresses scope name in any system of any kind (ipv4 or ipv6).

Comment: Is there any way to get scope name from sin6_scope_id?

Comment: Normally we do one struct ifaddrmsg *ifa = NLMSG_DATA(h); and use ifa->ifa_scope. But in my scope i do have only link information i.e, struct ifinfomsg *. So i am not able to extract scope of address and in ifinfomsg structure there is no scope field.

Comment: If this isn't what you search for, could you specify what you mean by an v4 address'es scope? (AFAIK, v4 does not have address scopes beyond these.)

Comment: my question would rather correct as: How to get scope of an IPv4 host?    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632284/how-to-get-scope-of-an-ipv6-host?rq=1    is for ipv6

Comment: An ipv4 host does not have a scope per se, that's what I wanted to say with my comment. The closest thing there is is the list of reserved address ranges. Since you've mentioned `ifinfomsg`, do you maybe mean the scope associated with a ipv4 route in Linux? If so, you'll have to use `RTM_GETADDR` (i.e. `ifaddrmsg`), because that information is address-specific (one interface can have multiple IPs).

Comment: i am implementing for the command "ip addr" with -f options. My bottleneck is with -f and scope option in ip addr as "ip -f inet6 address show scope global". Here before showing the link information i need to check whether the given scope is equal to the scope of the ip address of the current link. I am doing RTM_GETADDR after printing the link info as "ip addr" command do. But at point of printing link info i dont have the ifaddrmsg info so cant check scope directly. Its my way of implementation of ip addr command and cant change the design at this point. :(

Comment: A link can, and with v6 usually has, multiple IPs at the same time. AFAIK, there is no alternative to iterating over all the IPs associated with an interface before printing the interface information, to determine whether one with the desired scope exists. iproute2 [essentially does the same](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/shemminger/iproute2.git/tree/ip/ipaddress.c#n967).

Answer (score 0):

To match my [IP6 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14083657/175849): however as noted IP4 the classifications are a recommendation that have been enshrined in the IP6 protocol so not completely equivalent.

There are helper macros to assist:

```
#define IN_LINKLOCAL(i) (((uint32_t)(i) & 0xffff0000) == 0xa9fe0000)
#define IN_PRIVATE(i)   ((((uint32_t)(i) & 0xff000000) == 0x0a000000) || \
                         (((uint32_t)(i) & 0xfff00000) == 0xac100000) || \
                         (((uint32_t)(i) & 0xffff0000) == 0xc0a80000))

struct sockaddr_in s4;
if (IN_LOOPBACK(ntohl(s4->sin_addr.s_addr)) {
  puts ("loopback");
} else if (IN_MULTICAST(ntohl(s4->sin_addr.s_addr)) {
  puts ("multicast");
} else if (IN_BADCLASS(ntohl(s4->sin_addr.s_addr)) {
  puts ("reserved");
} else if (IN_LINKLOCAL(ntohl(s4->sin_addr.s_addr)) {
  puts ("link-local");
} else if (IN_PRIVATE(ntohl(s4->sin_addr.s_addr)) {
  puts ("private");
} else {
  puts ("global");
}
```